# when to use "the"

Tags: articles

In this sentence,

"This site made organizing and viewing "***the***" photos in groups a snap."

is the use of "the" correct? (assuming that there are no specifically mentioned photos in the context) Or should it just be "photos"?

I think the "the" can be used to represent photos in general, but was not so sure.

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: No - if the context doesn't clearly identify some *specific* photos to be referenced by ***the***, you shouldn't include the article.

Comment: 'This site' would not really be warranted unless you'd already discussed in general what you were doing / intending. If you've already communicated that you're dealing with image processors and/or managers, the definite article is licensed.

Comment: If "Groups" is an app, then "the photos in Groups" is the specified photos, and "Groups" needs a capital "G". Otherwise, it's a mistake

Answer (score 1):

"the" in this case would refer back to a set of photos that were already specified. E.g.

- "Once I uploaded all my vacation videos and photos, the site made organizing and viewing the photos in groups a snap."

If referring to photos in general, do not use "the":

- "The site made organizing and viewing photos in groups a snap."